# Mongoid overload of initialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I ran into this error using Mongoid with a rails model:

> NoMethodError:
>          undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

To simplify, my classes were declared as follows:

```
class Fruit
    include Mongoid::Document

    field :name, type: String

    def initialize
        self.name = 'fruit'
    end
end
```

Initially I couldn't figure out where this was coming from so I started paring things down. Taking the Mongoid::Document include out fixed the problem (but obviously wasn't ideal). After further massaging Google I found this discussion:

https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/1678

...which described the same problem. As I would like to use an initialize mechanism to set instance variables in subclasses, I came up with this solution:

```
class Fruit
    include Mongoid::Document

    field :name, type: String, default: ->{ self.do_init }

    def do_init
        self.name = 'fruit'
    end
end
```

This works, but seems less than ideal. Then again, maybe it's OK. I wanted to post this because a) I had a difficult time finding a description of a similar problem, and b) I though this was poorly documented in mongoid.

As I understand this, the Mongoid gem overloads initialize, and my attempt at overriding *initialize* re-overloads and breaks the Mongoid::Document initialization process.

Comment: Right; this was an example I typed up. Edited to correct above. Thanks for catching that

Comment: before_create is probably the closest equivalent to the Object::initialize pattern.thanks!

Comment: FWIW, I think `default: ->{ 'fruit' }` is a bit better because it uses a Mongoid idiom. Also, it is possible that overwriting `initialize` could have unexpected side effects.

Answer (score 5):

I have been trying to solve this problem for hours and just figured it out. You need to call super at the beginning of your initialize method. For example,

```
class Fruit
    include Mongoid::Document

    field :name, type: String

    def initialize
        super
        self.name = 'fruit'
    end
end
```

Unfortunately I do not know enough about ruby to give you an explanation of why this is needed. I don't completely understand how super works in this case, given that the super class is just Object.